# Firebase Storage Security. Why I can copy/paste the link tomy files and open them in the browser?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

this might be a very stupid question but I need to ask since I'm not very good with security, authentication etc. When I upload an image to Firebase Storage with an authenticated user in my React app the files get shown in the Storage dashboard. My security rules show that only authenticated users can write and read data. However when I click on an image it opens in the web browser with a link. So my questions is, how secure is that. I see that there is an access token but I'm not sure what is its role. Is it that only users with this token can access files? And by default authenticated users have it?

Please help
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you generated a "download URL" using the Firebase SDK, that URL will bypass security rules entirely.  It is considered an "unguessable, shareable" URL.  If this isn't what you want, then don't generate and share a download URL.  You will have to make people use your app to download the content using the SDK.

If you building a web app, you don't have much an alternative, as you need a download URL to populate an img tag that they can see.